# How to review customer basket before checkout for discount purpose?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

Is there any shopping cart that support this technique that admin can review a customer **basket/cart** items before his checkout.
if customer wishes for discount at run time i.e on live chat. Can admin update his basket for negotiated discount and let him go to checkout after update?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of search i found solution **View Client cart and wish list** extension using open cart.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your very own shopping cart. It should simply display the order ID or the cart ID which the customer should tell the chat representative. There should be an admin console where by the chat representative can add discount value there and save it. Thats it.

While programming such a cart you should make sure that the cart is not session based but database based, so that the data is available to the chat representative as well.

Regards.

Comment: thanks 
But i am asking for any plugin ,extension or any open source that uses same technique ?